# Javascript: How to change a button to another button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I wanted to take a button and change it to when clicked to another button using javascript, how would I write this in code?

This is all I have so far but its invalid :/

```
var change = document.getElementById("fire") === document.getElementById("water");
```

Comment: You want to change a button to another? Can you not change the value of the button or add a different function to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="fire">fire</button>
<button  id="water" style="visibility:hidden">water</button>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction()
{

document.getElementById("fire").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("water").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should make two buttons.

Make button A visible initially, button B hidden.
When button A is clicked, hide button A and make button B visible.

This can all be done with CSS. Checkout some jQuery tutorials.

Comment: This sounds like a simplest enough approach (without diving into DOM manipulation). However, more concrete details (or an example) would make this answer better.